# find size of react component or image before rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a list of images of different sizes.

```
images = ['https://example.com/1.jpg','https://example.com/2.jpg', ... ]
```

---

I want to get an array of their height before rendering them. I will then only render the images which should be in viewport based on scrollHeight. e.g using [React Infinte](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite)

I can do this easily outside react component

```
let imgHeights =  images.map(imgUrl => {
    var img  = new Image()
    img.src = imgUrl
    return img.height;
})
```

but `new image()` does not work in react since it depends on DOM.

My React component render method looks like this.

```
var ImageList = (images) => {
     let buildImageList = images.map(imgUrl => {
         return <img src= {imgUrl}></img>
     })

     let imgHeights = images.map(imgUrl => {
         let img = new Image()
         img.src = imgUrl
         return img.height //this doesn't work 
     })

     return (
         <Infinte elemetHeight = {imgHeights} onInfiniteLoad ={buildImageList} />
     ) 
}
```

How can I get The Image height? Should I use ReactDOM to render images in a temporary div?

Comment: Hmm that should work, because you're not really rendering the `new Image`, just using the api to get the height. When you say "doesn't work" can you elaborate what's not working? what does `img.height` return?

Comment: It returns 0 every time.

Comment: It returns 0. I think new Image depends on DOM

Comment: The problem is when you set the `src` property on the Image object, the browser fetches the image *asynchronously*. You need to register the `onload` callback to be notified when the image download finished. Only then can you get the size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Images are downloaded asynchronously while the javascript continues to execute, so you need to wait for them to load in order to record their heights. You could wait on their `onload` event and do something like

```
 let imgHeights = {};
 images.forEach(imgUrl => {
     let img = new Image();
     img.src = imgUrl;
     img.onload = () => imgHeights[imgUrl] = img.height;
 })
```

That just gets you started; you still have to figure out how to render them as they become ready.

Comment: It works. Sorry, I should have read the Image API more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a similar way to video?